# What is the probability of the event given below?

Tags: probability

A bag contains 3 white and 5 red balls. Another bag contains 4 white and 6 red balls. A ball is drawn from the first bag and then from the second bag. What is the probability of the ball being white?

Comment: What do you mean by "the" white ball? Do you mean "the balls" (aka both white) or "a ball" (meaning at least one)?

Comment: @kaine Both balls being white

Answer (score 1):

$(3/8)(4/10)$

3 white balls out of 8 from the first bag
and 4 white balls out of 10 from the second bag

Edit:

My bad, I didn't read so that both had to be white.
(first solution was flawed anyhow)

Comment: This cannot be correct.  This yields the expected number of white balls but not the probability of a white ball.  If you use this for the red balls, you would get $\frac{5}{8}+ \frac{6}{10} = \frac{49}{40}$ which does not make sense.

Comment: @kaine You're right. I wasn't thinking straight. If the questions was at least 1, you would have to break it into 3 cases.

1. White ball from bag 1, Red from bag 2. 
2. Red from bag 1, White from bag 2. 
3. Both bags give you white.